# Adding multiple graphic objects to one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, paintcomponent

Here is my code it is a guy and a background but only one thing shows up at a time or sometimes nothing at all.
I have a brain class, a frame class, a redPlayer class, and a background class.
The way it works is the brain makes a player and a brain and adds it to the frame.

I think it has something to do with layouts but I tried everything but nothing works.
Please Help!!!

Thanks in advance.

here is the brain:

```
 public class Brain 
 {
   private Frame frame;
   private static RedPlayer redPlayer;
   private Background background;
   private SensorKeys sensor;

public Brain()
{
    frame = new Frame();
    redPlayer = new RedPlayer();
    background = new Background();
    sensor = new SensorKeys();

    frame.addComponent(redPlayer);
    frame.addComponent(background);
    frame.addKeySensor(sensor);

    redPlayer.revalidate();
}

public static void setRedPlayerVelX(double vx)
{
    redPlayer.setVelX(vx);
}

public static void setRedPlayerVelY(double vy)
{
    redPlayer.setVelY(vy);
}

public static void makeRedPlayerBullet()
{

}
```

}
`

here is the frame class

```
public class Frame
{
private JFrame jf;

public Frame()
{
    drawFrame();
}

public void drawFrame()
{
    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setSize(800, 600);
    jf.setLocation(10, 10);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    jf.setLayout(null);
}

public void addComponent(JComponent jc)
{
    jc.setBounds(jc.getX(), jc.getY(), 100, 100);
    jf.add(jc);
}

public void addPanel(JPanel jp)
{
    jf.add(jp);
}

public void addKeySensor(KeyListener kl)
{
    jf.addKeyListener(kl);
}

 }
```

here is the player class:

```
public class RedPlayer extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
private int x,y;
private double velX = 0, velY = 0;
private Timer timer = new Timer(2,this);
private Image redplayer;

public RedPlayer()
{
    x = 100;
    y = 100;

    ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon("redPlayerRight.png");
    redplayer = II.getImage();

    revalidate();
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

    graphics.drawImage(redplayer, x,y, null);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{   
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    repaint();
    revalidate();
}


public void setVelX(double vx)
{
    velX = vx;
}

public void setVelY(double vy)
{
    velY = vy;
}   
}
```

And Lastly here is the background class:

```
public class Background extends JComponent
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

    graphics.setColor(Color.green);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 400, 500, 200);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think it has something to do with layouts

Yes, you should read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to better understand how they work and for examples.

The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. You can't just add 3 components to the same area of the BorderLayout.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but start simple. Since you have a background the basic code should be something like:

```
redPlayer = new RedPlayer();
background = new Background();
background.add( redPlayer );
frame.addComponent(background);
```

So the red player should display on top of the background. And the background is added to the frame.

Of course you must use a proper layout manager for the background. And you must make sure you override the getPreferredSize() method when you do custom painting so the layout manager knows what the size of every component should be.

Get those two components working first, then move on to the 3rd component.

Comment: The background is a jcomponent that should be added to the jframe just like the player class. I've looked over that tutorial on layout managers several times but it never works.

Comment: You can't just add components to the frame and expect them to be painted on top of one another. That is why you need to structure your code the way I suggested. I know it doesn't work. You haven't implemented the getPreferredSize() method in any of your classes. You need to first add a "background" component to your frame. Once you get that to work you try adding a component to your background. Don't try to write the entire program at once. Learn the basics of using a layout manager first.